# Can we compare algorithms using big oh?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have been googling about Big O notation from past three days and came to the following conclusions.

1. Big O notation just tells us how the time taken by an algorithm grows as we increase the input size.
2. We can compare only algorithms from two different classes and not from the same class i.e; we can compare `O(n^2)` with `O(n)` but not with `O(n^2)` of some other algorithm.
3. We omit the constants as we are only considered about growth.

After having all this clarification, I still have a doubt:

1. We know that `O(10n)` is slower than `O(n^2)` for `n<10`. Then how can we say that the algorithm of order `O(n)` is always best than `O(n^2)` without actually considering the constants?

   How can we state that the algorithm of time complexity `O(n)` is always best?
2. If we have `f(n)=10n^2+5n+6`, we omit `10` as the function always increase by a constant 10. But why do we also omit `5n+6` (not constant)? Isn't it significant in function growth?

Comment: 1) This assumption is incorrect. There are algorithms with worse complexity that are indeed better in practice for all input sizes of relevance. Big-O, as you figured out, does not tell you whats better in terms of actual time. It only measures **asymptotic growth**. So an algorithm with worse complexity will **eventually** be worse (if the input size is high enough). But that threshold might totally be beyond whats reasonable in practice. Small example from practice, `ArrayList` (dynamic arrays) are better than `LinkedList` in practice, eventhough they have worse complexity for some ops.

Comment: 2) 5n+6 is certainly smaller than `k * n^2` for some `k`. Then you have `10kn^2` and `10k` is a constant, you end up in `n^2`.

Comment: All in all, id suggest you stop learning big-o "by pattern" or "by feel" and instead get familiar with the actual mathematical definition and start working with it, actually correctly proving cases. That way you will fully understand whats happening. `exists C > 0, exists n_0 > n, for all n > n_0: f(n) <= C * g(n)` then and only then `f in O(g)`.

Comment: Big O is not meant to be precise. It can help classify solutions to problems but it doesn't actually tell you which is "better". A `O(1)` (constant) algorithm can be *slower* than `O(n^2)` algorithm. If the constant time it takes is exactly 20 hours, then it's *slow* but consistent. While `O(n^2)` may take 1 second per `n` which would mean that it's faster until *approximately* `n = 720000` Yet maybe your input doesn't go above 100. Similarly, higher complexity algorithms might end up being faster than lower complexity ones but for different input size. E.g. bubble sort vs quicksort for `n=10`

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean with your comparison-statement in the first 2). You can compare any function with any other function in terms of complexity. Also note that big-o is informally `<=`. So `5n in O(n^4)` is a true statement. I.e. it does not have to be a tight bound. Tight bounds are measured by big-theta, not big-o. (The other direction is given by big-omega).

Comment: @Zabuzard Thanks for the clarification. Now i get it why 5n+6 is ignored.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the clarification. But I still have a doubt. If we can't compare two algorithms based on big oh then what's the point of having this concept? For what purpose do we use big oh?

Comment: @veerrajuannamdevula Majority of the time, the outcome of a big-o analysis is actually spot-on and translates to real-time reasonably well. Its a tool and it can be abused for sure. Its more commonly used for research-ish topics, such as general algorithm research. For example you can easily prove that its impossible to find a comparison-based sorting algorithm that runs better than `n * log(n)` (complexity-wise). Which is a very interesting observation.

Comment: So most of the time Big-O is accurate and helpful. But sometimes it can be abused and hide important facts. So its still important that you actually do proper benchmark rather than just a complexity analysis. Again, I like to bring up `ArrayList` vs `LinkedList`. Removal in an ArrayList is O(n), in LinkedList its O(1) (after node location). But ArrayList is still faster in majority of real world scenarios. Simply because arrays are so hugely optimized (cache locality etc). So in this case Big-O can fool people.

Comment: @Zabuzard so it's not worth of having the concept big oh. Is it?I still really can't figure out what's the point of having big oh if we can't really compare to know the execution time of an algorithm.

Comment: Did you fully read what I said? I stressed twice already that Big-O is, most of the time, spot-on and translates well to real-world-time. There are just a couple of exceptions where an actual benchmark shows different results than Big-O would _suggest_. It is a good tool to compare algorithms, most of the time it also tells you which one is actually better in terms of real time, and you also have to stop seeing Big-O only with your "programming googles" on. There is more to computer science than pure programming.

Comment: The comments confuse more: The OP now sais "If we can't compare two algorithms then what's the point of having this concept?. This statement is just incorrect. We are talking about algorithms. And we compare them. Big-O is the most important thing to know. All your other details are implementation details. The recommendation "stop learning Big-O" is like ignoring common knowledge of computer science and practice. The recommendation to see Big-O only as an asymptotic thing is like forgetting that it is a concept, forgetting abstraction, looking only on complicated formulas and get lost in them.

Answer (score 1):

> Big O notation just tells us how the time taken by an algorithm grows as we increase the input size.

It only tells us how the time taken grows **asymptotically**. This means you cannot even make conclusions about the time taken for one input size compared to the time taken for another input size. Given an implemented function , a run of (=100) may even be faster than a run of (n=90), **whatever** the time complexity of that function is.

> We can compare only algorithms from two different classes and not from the same class i.e; we can compare O(n^2) with O(n) but not with O(n^2) of some other algorithm.

If you are comparing execution times, then again, the given time complexities tell us *nothing* concerning the actual execution times of two algorithms. The difference in asymptotic behaviour may only become noticeable in their execution times for input sizes that are impractically large.

> We omit the constants as we are only considered about growth.

It is not really about growth -- a function may temporarily show a descending slope for increasing input sizes -- but asymptotic behaviour. When the input size increases towards infinity, a constant eventually becomes irrelevant.

> We know that O(10n) is slower than O(n^2) for n<10.

No, we do not know that.

For instance, compare these two algorithms:

```
Func1(n):
    for i = 1 to 10 * n:
        sleep(1 millisecond)
        
Func2(n):
    for i = 1 to n*n:
        sleep(1 second)
```

Here Fun1 is O(10) = O() and Func2 is O(²). Func1 will never be slower than Func2.

One cannot compare two time complexities in terms of "slower".

> Then how can we say that the algorithm of order O(n) is always best than O(n^2) without actually considering the constants?

We don't say that. On the contrary, this overhead of constants (and linear coefficients, ...etc) **does** play a role in deciding which algorithm to use. For instance, this is why quick sort is quite popular, even though there are sorting algorithms whose worst case time complexity is better.

> How can we state that the algorithm of time complexity O(n) is always best?

We don't state that. And don't forget there are sub-lineair algorithms, whose time complexity is O(log), or even O(1).

> If we have f(n)=10n^2+5n+6, we omit 10 as the function always increase by a constant 10. But why do we also omit 5n+6 (not constant)? Isn't it significant in function growth?

The part that the lower graded terms play in the function becomes less and less important the higher the value of . For instance, when  is 10000, the terms 5+6 only influence the value by 0.005%, and it becomes more and more negligible as we increase . Asymptotically it has lost all its impact. And so all that remains is ²

Comment: You said that the time complexities tell us nothing concerning the actual execution times. That is not correct. Making statements about the actual execution time is the motivation of all this. You try to emphasise that in practical life the complexity theory does not play such a big role. This was not the question. The question was why does it make sense to ignore the lower order terms. And you explained that it makes sense not to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

When an algorithm has time complexity O(N²) [for the sake of example], all we know is that its actual running time does not exceed cN² as of a certain N.

First, it can be that the bound is not tight, so that the true time would be like cN log²N or cN^1.993. It could also be that the running time is comprised between 3N+125 and 2N²-3√N, depending on the particular input.

Now if the bound is tight and the algorithm has a smooth behavior, we could indeed have a time equal to cN² + low order terms. If you want to compare two algorithms based on this you should

- check for what minimal value of N this behavior holds (if the value of N is astronomical, you have in fact no usable information);
- check if the low order terms are truly neglectable for the practical values of N;
- get an estimate of the c constants of both algorithms for a real implementation;
- estimate the breakeven point (where c F(N) = c' G(N)).

This is the theoretical approach. In practice you are rarely in a position to apply it. Benchmarking is your friend.

---

Anyway, you can use the following rules of thumb:

- O(N log N) is often better than O(N²) for medium and large values of N;
- O(N log N) may fail to beat O(N) for moderate values of N;
- N² is preferable over N³ for moderate values of N;
- higher order polynomials or super-polynomial functions are only usable for limited values of N, so that slight differences between the complexities (say O(N^5) vs. O(2^N)) might not matter.

Comment: You don't actually answered the two questions. You tried to illustrate that in your theoretical approach the low order terms are important. But the questions was why they are not important.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few intuitive and easy answers.

1. Normally we are not interested how an algorithm performs for small input size, because for small input sizes, nearly everything is fast. Optimising something that is already fast is a waste of time. Therefore when comparing algorithms we don't ever look at this. If for example in real life you want to solve a puzzle with 9 pieces, you will always be fast, regardless of what algorithm you use or what picture is on the puzzle. Only if you have a puzzle of 1000 pieces you may want to have a strategy (e.g. doing the border first).
2. It is true that the 5n+6 are not of interest. If you only look at big input sizes then only n^2 is of interest. Let's see a practical exammple: You have an algorithm that needs 10n^2+5n+6 ms. You input has a size of 100. So you wait 10*x100^2+5x100+6 = 100000 + 500 + 6 = 100506 ms. The value 10n^2 = 100000 is already very close to this result and the 506 do not really matter. If you have to wait one Minute and 40 seconds for a result than you don't care if it is 506 ms sooner or later. You always have this phenomenon, even for extreme cases like 1.0001n^2 + 100000n. The quadratic grow is dominant.
3. Your sentence in question 2 that you ignore 10 because it is a constant is a bit imprecise. In your example 6 is a constant. 10 is a constant factor. That is a difference. You may wonder why we are not interested in this constant factor. The answer is that we want to talk about the algorithm only and not how well it is implemented or executed. Again an example: If you program an algorithm in Java and execute it on a slow machine, the result may take 10 times longer than the same algorithm implemented in Assembler and executed on a fast machine. But this is obvious. This is no information with value. The constant factor is more a question how fast your algorithm is executed but not a question how good your algorithm is. And therefore we don't look at constant factors.